# Color all elements except for first CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

This is my example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/84mq6bLr/

I would like to color all elements except for the first paragraph.

I know that if I use li instead of classes or even if i put classes in the li, I would fix this problem, but the structure is as in example.

Any suggestions?

```
.dd ~ .dd {
    background:#ff0000;
 }
```

Comment: The markup matters, having it in the fiddle is not good enough.

Comment: Have a look on `pseudoclasses` in CSS. But what confuses me in your example is that you say you want to change `color`, and your css rule mentions `background`. Background and color are two different concepts.

Comment: you could do `li ~ li .dd {background:#ff0000;}` demo: http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/84mq6bLr/9/

Answer (score 4):

```
li:nth-child(n+2) p{
    background:#ff0000;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/gxqqct6u/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
.dd{
    background:#ff0000;
}
ul li:first-child .dd{
    background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS selector called `first-child` that you could use. You can see it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/84mq6bLr/8/

```
li>p.dd {
    background-color:#ff0000;
}
li:first-child>p.dd {
    background-color:initial;
}
```

Basically, it reads as "look for the first `li` element in any group, then find any paragraph within it with a class of `dd`, then reset it's color to it's default`.

This probably won't work in older browsers (such as IE8).

Comment: Why would you use first-of-type here as opposed to more widely supported options (sibling selector, nth-child, etc.)?  The only children allowed for ul elements is li.

Comment: @cimmanon - you're right, and I learned something today :)
The example has been updated to use the `child` selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
li:not(:first-child)>p {
    background-color: #900;
}
```

Updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/84mq6bLr/7/